# super stalemate

Tags: problems, stalemate

Your challenge.
Find a position such that one side cannot make any legal *or illegal* moves. I.E. Make it such that that even if you were allowed to move your king into check there would still be no legal moves.

Answer (score 2):

An empty board is the only solution.

As soon as there are pieces on the board, they can move in some way (capturing your own pieces is an illegal move which is now allowed).